# Need help identifying a rogue app

Tags: iphone, applications

After iOS 10.3.3 I cant backup my iPhone due to the "iPhone disconnected" bug.  I used a sync analyzer software and it reports the backup error occurring on an Application located in `/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/4D762153-8922-432E-AE2B-2A02A1F1F710`.

How can I identify the app name from this UUID so that I can try uninstalling it?